# Downloading pictures (png etc.) on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I can't find a way to download images from Google images and save them to my files on my raspberry pi. Whenever I right click it just says open it in a new tab or go back a page. How can I download pictures?

Thanks in advance and sorry for being a noob!

Answer (score 2):

From the console (=SSH) you can just go into your folder where you want the picture and type

```
wget <url>
```

and it saves!